# startRecur does not have a proper date

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use fullcalendar, I'm putting the schoolClass at the correct hours, but it repeat everyday:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwD2D.png

When I'm doing right -> inspect and go check my js, here is what I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvPBj.png

As you can see, the year/month/day of startRecur and endRecur is not initilize correctly.. Here is how I'm doing it:

In my SchoolClass.cs:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Date of the schoolclass")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime DayClass{ get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Start time")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime StartTime{ get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "End Time")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime EndTime{ get; set; }
```

And this function:

```
   [Display(Name = "start")]
    public string startTime
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", StartTime);
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "end")]
    public string endTime
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", EndTime);
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "recurStart")]
    public string fusionStart
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("0:yyyy-MM-dd", DayClass)+"T"+ StartTime;
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "recurEnd")]
    public string fusionEnd
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("0:yyyy-MM-dd", DayClass) + "T" +  endTime;
        }
    }
```

And thats what I do where I use fullcalendar:

```
events: [
    @foreach (var item in Model.Seance)
    {
    @:{
       @:title: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JourSeance)',
       @:start: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JourSeance)',
       @:startTime: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startTime)',
       @:end: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JourSeance)',
       @:endTime: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.endTime)',
       @:startRecur: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateFusionneDebut)',
       @:endRecur: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateFusionneFin)'
      @:},
     }
   ]
```

Cordially

Comment: Resolved, thanks for your help :D

Comment: Please post your solution, or if it was trivial, delete the question. Thanks